# Nginx demorando para registrar todos os serviços no docker swarm

Tags: nginx

Tenho uma stack com docker-swarm com uns 80 contêineres que quando preciso recriá-la inteira demora mais de uma hora para subir completamente pois o NGINX fica dando alertas e tentando fazer a conexão com os contêineres com o erro abaixo:

```
2019/04/25 10:12:55 [emerg] 4246#4246: host not found in upstream "prd_teste_cliente" in /etc/nginx/upstreams/upstream_prd_teste_cliente.conf:3
ftc-ed_nginx.1.unqyfjytn6r3@edworker01    | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "prd_teste_cliente" in /etc/nginx/upstreams/upstream_prd_teste_cliente.conf:3
```

O arquivo upstream está desta forma:

```
upstream prd_teste_cliente {
 least_conn;
 server prd_teste_cliente max_fails=1 fail_timeout=60 weight=1 max_conns=100;
}
```

O nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server_names_hash_max_size 512;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;
client_max_body_size 256m;
keepalive_timeout  0;

#gzip  on;

# Enable Cache Support
proxy_cache_path /data/nginx/cache/app levels=1:2 keys_zone=app:10m max_size=2g inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;

real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive on;

proxy_connect_timeout       300000;
proxy_send_timeout          300000;
proxy_read_timeout          300000;
send_timeout                300000;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

server {
    listen 8081;
    server_name 10.0.213.5;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 128k;
    location / {
            stub_status;
    }
    location /server_status {
            stub_status;
    }
}
}
```

Arquivo location:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name cliente.teste.com.br;
  gzip on;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_comp_level 4;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml;
  gzip_min_length 1400;
  server_tokens off;
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
  proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;
  client_header_timeout 5s;
  client_body_timeout 5s;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://prd_teste_cliente;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_connect_timeout 600000;
    proxy_send_timeout 600000;
    proxy_read_timeout 600000;
    send_timeout 600000;
  }
}
```